# Can all LEGO Loco characters be recreated in real life?

Tags: minifigures, video-games

The 1998 game [LEGO Loco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Loco) features a plethora of Minifigs that roam around the city:
[image: Image showcasing the characters of Lego Loco]

Can all these characters be recreated with real minifig parts?

Comment: You can likely get close, but some of these parts are fictitious. For example, [magenta mohawk](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=93563&colorID=71) exists but is a slightly different color and does not have two rows of knobs as depicted.

Comment: Also, the "moonshine" jug the character with the straw hat is carrying doesn't seem to exist. There are a few wine bottles but [this jug](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4429) is the closest I could find and it has significant differences.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Only five characters can be built *exactly* (denoted by ✅). Another 11 can be made quite closely (). The other 12 I believe are partially or entirely made up (❌).

I tried to make sure all parts were available at the time of the game, exceptions are stated.

The image of each part is also a link to [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com).

## Row 1

### ❌ Figure 1 - Polka Dot Lady

I initially thought the hair looked like [Hair Male](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62711&C=5) with some extra bits printed on the face, even though that part does not exist in red. User [Steve Bennett](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/18699/steve-bennett) pointed out, and I agree now, that those extra parts do appear to be part of the hair piece.
This hair piece looks like a similar style, but released after the game.
I could not find a torso that matches, but I found a kind-of similar one.

[image: fig 1 full]
[image: fig 1]
[image: fig 1]
or
[image: fig 1]
[image: fig 1]
[image: fig 1]

### ❌ Figure 2

The hair appears to be white, but it does not exist.
I could not find a torso that matches, it looks like a variation of the [banker's jacket](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0194c01&C=9).

[image: fig 2 full]
[image: fig 2]
[image: fig 2]
[image: fig 2]

It looks like he's holding a briefcase.

[image: case]

### Figure 3 - Girl

The hair might not be an exact match, but it's the only hair with pigtails that existed at the time of the game. The developers might have also taken some creative liberties.
I'm also tempted to think it could just be [Hair Male](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62711&C=5) again with pigtails added.
It appears there are some very faint glasses, but I couldn't find any such face.
There is a more modern hair piece that could work too.
As user [Darrel Hoffman](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/11559/darrel-hoffman) pointed out, there are shorter legs available. However, these do not articulate and are a slightly different shade of pink to the other pinks.

[image: fig 3 full]
[image: fig 3]
or
[image: fig 3](+ pigtails)
or
[image: fig 3]
[image: fig 3]
[image: fig 3]
[image: fig 3]
or
[image: fig 3]

### Figure 4 - Lee (Skateboarder)

Lee's torso doesn't seem to match any exactly, but two match closely.
It seems that Lego only begun producing skateboards in 2003, but included one anyway. (yellow wheels don't exist)

[image: fig 4 full]
[image: fig 4]
[image: fig 4]
[image: fig 4]
or
[image: fig 4]
[image: fig 4]
[image: skateboard]

### Figure 5 - Construction Lady

The hat does not exist in green.

[image: fig 5 full]
[image: fig 5]
[image: fig 5]
[image: fig 5]
[image: fig 5]

### ✅ Figure 6 - Eamon (Skeleton)

Just a regular skeleton.

[image: fig 6 full]
[image: fig 6]

### Figure 7 - Police Officer

No hat exists with that pattern.

[image: fig 7 full]
[image: fig 7]
[image: fig 7]
[image: fig 7]
[image: fig 7]

## Row 2

### ✅ Figure 8

Swap black hands for yellow. (Note other small differences in the torso)

[image: fig 8 full]
[image: fig 8]
[image: fig 8]
[image: fig 8]
[image: fig 8]

### ✅ Figure 9 - Boy

As user [Darrel Hoffman](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/11559/darrel-hoffman) pointed out, there are shorter legs available. The medium ones articulate, but the short ones are also available in pink for the girl (#3).

[image: fig 9 full]
[image: fig 9]
[image: fig 9]
[image: fig 9]
[image: fig 9]
or
[image: fig 9]
or
[image: fig 9]

### ❌ Figure 10 - Milkman

Surprisingly, I couldn't find this torso.

[image: fig 10 full]
[image: fig 10]
[image: fig 10]
[image: fig 10]

Milk bottles don't exist, but could be simulated with

[image: milk]
[image: milk] x 2

### ❌ Figure 11 - Grandma

I couldn't find hair that match, nor a female head with grey eyebrows. It could just be [Hair Male](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62711&C=5) with buns.
The torso has yellow arms, instead of pink.
The hips are also pink, not light grey.

[image: fig 11 full]
[image: fig 11]
[image: fig 11]
[image: fig 11]
[image: fig 11]

### ❌ Figure 12 - Big Brain Scientist

This oversized head does not exist. I couldn't find a matching face either.

[image: fig 12 full]
[image: fig 12]
[image: fig 12]

### ❌ Figure 13

The hair has the same options as #3.
I couldn't find the head or torso. I suspect the head is made up since it has a nose, which is not something Lego does for standard minifigures (#9's face is one such exception).
Lego does definitely not add a "contour" to its torsos either.
This torso also looks like an extreme variation of the [banker's jacket](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0194c01&C=9).

[image: fig 13 full]
[image: fig 13]
or
[image: fig 3](+ pigtails)
or
[image: fig 3]
[image: fig 13]

### ❌ Figure 14 - [Sid Vacant](https://legostuntrally.fandom.com/wiki/Sid_Vacant)?

This one also appears entirely made up. However, Lego did create a mohawk piece after the game was developed. (as pointed out by Fredric Shope in a comment)
This torso is the closest I could find, just add the bare yellow arms.

[image: fig 14 full]
[image: fig 14]
[image: fig 14]
[image: fig 14]

## Row 3

### Figure 15 - Necklace Lady

The same face as #13 (not winking, though).

[image: fig 15 full]
[image: fig 15]
[image: fig 15]
[image: fig 15]

### Figure 16 - Angry Banker

I believe the face is has just been given the angry expression in this rendering.
Note that the torso appears dark grey, and the green seems to have been removed.

[image: fig 16 full]
[image: fig 16]
[image: fig 16]
[image: fig 16]
[image: fig 16]

### Figure 17 - Walking Stick Man

It looks like he has a walking stick, which doesn't exist.

[image: fig 17 full]
[image: fig 17]
[image: fig 17]
[image: fig 17]

### ❌ Figure 18 - *Hillbilly*

This guy is entirely made up.

[image: fig 18 full]

### ✅ Figure 19 - Dr. Cyber?

This is almost [Dr Cyber](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=tim003) from Time Cruisers, but with grey hair.

[image: fig 19 full]
[image: fig 19]
[image: fig 19]

### Figure 20

Similar to the banker, the face has been made angry.

[image: fig 20 full]
[image: fig 20]
[image: fig 20]
[image: fig 20]
[image: fig 20]

### ❌ Figure 21

This torso also looks like a non-existent variation of the [banker's jacket](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0194c01&C=9).

[image: fig 21 full]
[image: fig 21]
[image: fig 21]
[image: fig 21]

## Row 4

### ✅ Figure 22 - Police Officer

I don't think his head exists, but it could be based on this.

[image: fig 22 full]
[image: fig 22]
[image: fig 22]
[image: fig 22]
[image: fig 22]

### ❌ Figure 23

This torso looks like yet another non-existent variation of the [banker's jacket](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0194c01&C=9), but I've added a similar one I found.

[image: fig 23 full]
[image: fig 23]
[image: fig 23]
[image: fig 23]

### ❌ Figure 24 - Pop Star

His head and torso are almost certainly made up, but other options added.

[image: fig 24 full]
[image: fig 24]
[image: fig 24]
or
[image: fig 24]
[image: fig 24]
or
[image: fig 24]
or
[image: fig 24]
[image: fig 24]

### ❌ Figure 25

The same face and torso (different colour) as #13.

[image: fig 25 full]
[image: fig 25]
[image: fig 25]

### Figure 26 - [Intelligent Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Games) employee?

The hat does not exist in any grey/silver colours, but could possibly be black. I didn't find the torso.

[image: fig 26 full]
[image: fig 26]
[image: fig 26]
[image: fig 26]

### Figure 27 - Mechanic

Same head as #22.

[image: fig 27 full]
[image: fig 27]
[image: fig 27]
[image: fig 27]
[image: fig 27]

No wrench like this exists, but this one existed when the game was made.

[image: wrench]

And this one came after.

[image: wrench2]

### Figure 28 - Sad

Same face as #13, #15, and #25.

[image: fig 28 full]
[image: fig 28]
[image: fig 28]
[image: fig 28]

Comment: Fantastic work! This will help me a lot in recreating most of these around my city. It surprises me that the mohawk isn't a real piece - The 2000 videogame Lego Stunt Rally features the character [Sid Vacant](https://legostuntrally.fandom.com/wiki/Sid_Vacant) that has the same hair piece. (in fact it might even be the same character) I vaguely remember seeing it in some flash games as well, so I always assumed it was real.

Comment: Figure 1 (polka dot lady)'s hair doesn't look that close to "hair male" to me. It has much sharper sideburns (or whatever you call those), with a big gap between the tuft of hair and the rest of the hair up the top.

Comment: @SteveBennett You may be right, I initially thought the "sideburns and tuft" were printed on.

Comment: Note that while the 2 kids are at least partially reproduceable (the boy more than the girl in this case), they won't be to scale - i.e. they'll be the same size as the other figures, not smaller as they appear in the image.  There are some child-sized legs you can get, but they aren't articulated like normal legs, so won't be a perfect match.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Good point, I'll add it, although Lego now produces medium legs (one plate shorter than normal) which _do_ articulate the same as normal legs